# upload data to redshift using nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I followed the link https://walkingtree.tech/loading-data-to-redshift-using-nodejs/ and follow the step that creates an index.js file.
However, I don't understand the code app.post('/',)
The code that i modify is as below

```
app.post('/', function (request, response) {
// console.log(request.body);
// var body = [];
// var body = JSON.stringify(request.body);
// body.push(request.body.test) ;
var file_name = 'items.txt';
// csvbody = [Object.values(request.body)];
// console.log(body);
csvbody = ["abc","lalala"];
console.log(csvbody);
```

is the syntax correct that csvbody = ["abc","lalala"]; to upload to s3 ? and the local host 3001 shown that cannot get /. What should I do further?

Comment: That page says: _"The server will be available on localhost:3001 which you can test from the postman by passing 2 key value pairs (first number and second character as per the structure of our test1 table). This will first send data into S3 as a csv file and finally insert the data into the redshift test1 table."_ So, it is designed to upload data that is sent to a URL, but you seem to want to modify it to upload from a file? If so, how do you want to trigger the upload? This might not be a good sample program for you to copy.

Comment: it's fine to pass to '/' URL or upload through a file. Currently I upload through a file so as to test that it could work fine.

Comment: The best way to load bulk data into an Amazon Redshift database is to use the `COPY` command to load a file from Amazon S3. If you already have a file, you should place that file in S3, then call the COPY command with a reference to that file. Is there a particular reason you are wanting to do it from Node.js code? What will be triggering your upload?

Comment: yes, I have already used the COPY command to load a file from Amazon S3 and upload it to redshift. The reason that i would like to via nodejs is that later on i would like to like creating an online form for users to enter information and wanna upload the individual inputted data to redshift.

Comment: If you are inserting a single row of data (or a few rows), it is easier to simply construct an `INSERT` statement and send that to Redshift (instead of the `COPY` statement). That will avoid the need to use S3.

Comment: Do u mean simply use INSERT in nodejs instead of through s3 and copy command? but I am confusing how to get rid of cannot get /.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235292/discussion-between-mo-jiebu-and-john-rotenstein).